# Chroma keying a background to a green screen animated GIF

Tags: gimp, animation, gif

There are some GIMP tutorials about adding a background for a green screen GIF, i.e. chroma keying. But none of them is about a green screen animated GIF (e.g. [the "Confused Travolta" meme](https://i.imgur.com/mkhFnmC.gifv)).

GIMP can open animated GIFs. But can a background be added?

Comment: I don't use gimp, but my guess is that while one frame isn't that hard to key out, repeating the same process on multiple frames might not be as simple with gimp. Typically you'd use a video editing application to do this. As you might know, this exact video is part of a [tutorial for keying out the bg with Sony vegas pro](http://imgur.com/gallery/JWFFe). Other apps you could use: Premiere, After effects, Final cut pro, Hitfilm, Davinci resolve, Windows movie maker, iMovie... etc.

Answer (score 3):

An animated gif is a sequence of images (in your example, 100 images), and is technically possible - but obviously not suggested - open the file with the GIMP and edit each layer.

As you said, there are a lot of simple solutions for images with an alpha background (perhaps the simpler way is described [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22201/is-it-possible-to-add-a-background-image-to-all-layers-of-an-animated-gif)), but replacing a color is a bit difficult. There is an old GIMP plugin, the **GIMP Animation Package or GAP**, which is designed to work on multiple layers. [Here](http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=8940) is the answer to a question similar to yours.

Last version of GAP is for GIMP 2.6, but it seems to work even with GIMP 2.8 (read [here](http://registry.gimp.org/node/27483)).

Another way is use [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/):

```
convert test.gif -fill "#fb8245" -opaque "#1cd000" another_color.gif
```

[image: another background]

I've posted here just a frame, but convert works on all the layers. *#1CD000* is the green to be replaced. You can also replace the green background with a transparent one, using "none" as a fill color (and adding an alpha channel):

```
convert test.gif -alpha set -channel RGBA -fill none -opaque "#1cd000" alpha_bg.gif
```

[image: alpha background]

As you see, in the image there are a lot of boring pixels of other kind of green. ImageMagick comes out with the [fuzz](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#fuzz) modifier (you can adjust it by trying):

```
convert test.gif -fuzz 15% -alpha set -channel RGBA -fill none -opaque "#1cd000" alpha_bg.gif
```

[image: a bit of fuzzy threshold]

On ImageMagick websiste there are a lot of pages related to [generate](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/) or [modifying](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/) animations. Try and enjoy!

For a more professional work in my opinion you need an animation specific package.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed ideas! It should be noted ImageMagick breaks the animated GIF into different frames, which require a different program to piece them together again. With that said, can ImageMagick also append a certain background image to all those frames?

Comment: ImageMagick performs this operation **without** breaking the GIF in frames (the process is done only **in the memory** of the program, try the command in my answer!). Why do you think it should necessary perform a 2-step operation (and with a different program to piece the frames)? It would be absolutely not practical! ImageMagick *can* split the GIF in frames (if you need it) and it can also add a background (see [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/#cleared)) to the animation. I suggest you to **read** the documentation, **try** by yourself and **update** us on your efforts.

Comment: @LWC Video editing applications are way more equipped to handle video editing. To me it seems foolish to try to find alternative ways, since there are many free video editing applications out there, that give you way more control

Comment: What do you mean, I wrote it because I ran your command and it has splitted up the files into frames.
Anyway, GIF is an image file in the end so it lives in both worlds.

Comment: @LWC Even though gif is a moving _image_, image editing applications aren't well equipped for keying multiple frames. Also, you can make any video into a gif, but that doesn't mean it makes sense to edit it as a gif or in image editing application. The last point I'm going to make is that the file you have there is .gifv, which is Imgur's flavor of gif, which is actually a container for either .webm or .mp4, which are both video formats. If you want to do it the hard way, I'm not going to try and stop you any longer.